# Run-time Indication of Android Task Stack

Tags: android, stack, task, multitasking, android-launcher

I'm currently writing a custom launcher application for an embedded Android device of mine.
My intention is to delve into Android Task Stack mechanism.

Having finished studying the [official documents and guides](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html), now I have even more questions in my mind. So many cases that I can't possibly begin to share. So I thought to myself what if I could see what really happens to Task Stacks at the run-time of applications.

**In a nutshell:** I would like to have an observation of Task Stacks.

I was wondering if there exist any tool, library or application that allows me to view a real-time demonstration of Task Stack state, in action.

Any hint regarding where to begin is much appreciated.

Comment: Unless there is something in **`adb shell dumpsys`** that relates to what you need, I am not aware of anything else that exists. Also, please bear in mind that "questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam".

Comment: Nope, I don't want anybody's favorite tool. I wanna know if there is anything available.